# How can I paste above the default email signature?

Tags: excel, vba

```vb
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Dim ol As Object 'Outlook.Application 
Dim olEmail As Object 'Outlook.MailItem 
Dim olInsp As Object 'Outlook.Inspector 
Dim wd As Object 'Word.Document 
Dim rCol As Collection, r As Range, i As Integer

'if outlook is running use GO, create otherwise 
Set ol = GetObject(Class:="Outlook.Application") 
Set olEmail = ol.CreateItem(0) 'olMailItem

Set rCol = New Collection 
With rCol 
    .Add Sheet1.Range("B6:C23") '/\* add your ranges the same sequence \*/ 
End With

With olEmail 
.To = "email@domain.com" 
.CC = "anotheremail@domain.com" 
.Subject = "Useful subject" 
Set olInsp = .GetInspector 
If olInsp.EditorType = 4 Then 'olEditorWord 
Set wd = olInsp.WordEditor 
For i = 1 To rCol.Count '/\* iterate all ranges \*/ 
Set r = rCol.Item(i): r.Copy 
wd.Range.InsertParagraphAfter wd.Paragraphs(wd.Paragraphs.Count).Range.PasteAndFormat 16 '16 - wdFormatOriginalFormatting 
Next 
End If 

wd.Range.InsertParagraphAfter 
.Display 
End With

End Sub
```

This code copies and pastes into new Outlook email under the default signature.

The selection needs pasting before the signature, in the logical place of the beginning of the email.

Comment: did you want to paste each cell into each line in the email body?

Comment: @k1dr0ck I'm not quite sure. What happens now is it pastes the two columns directly under the signature. It looks exactly like it does in Excel, which is what I wanted. So just need something that says "do exactly what you're doing but starting above the email signature".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move the cursor above the signature before pasting.

```vb
Option Explicit


Private Sub CommandButton1_Click2()

Dim ol As Object        'Outlook.Application
Dim olEmail As Object   'Outlook.MailItem
Dim olInsp As Object    'Outlook.Inspector

Dim wd As Object        'Word.Document
Dim wdRng As Object     'Word.Range

Dim r As Range

' No need to differentiate CreateObject and GetObject for Outlook
' The result of either is the one allowed instance of Outlook
Set ol = CreateObject(Class:="Outlook.Application")
Set olEmail = ol.CreateItem(0) 'olMailItem

Set r = Sheet1.Range("B6:C23")

With olEmail
    .To = "email@domain.com"
    .CC = "anotheremail@domain.com"
    .Subject = "Useful subject"
    Set olInsp = .GetInspector
    
    If olInsp.EditorType = 4 Then 'olEditorWord - True since 2007
        Set wd = olInsp.WordEditor
        Set wdRng = wd.Range(0, 0)  ' Move the cursor to the start
        
        r.Copy
        wdRng.Paste ' Paste should not overwrite signature
    End If
    
    .Display
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you very much. That does precisely what I need now and my project is back on track.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
Sub SendEmailWithRange()
    Dim MyRange As Range
    Dim doc As Object,x
    
    Set MyRange = Sheet1.Range("B6:C23")
    
    With CreateObject("outlook.application").CreateItem(0)
        .Display  'Change to .Send to send the email immediately
        
        .Body = "This is the body:"      
        Set doc = .GetInspector.WordEditor
        
        x = doc.Range.End - 1
        MyRange.Copy
        doc.Range(x).Paste
          
        .To = "email@domain.com"
        .CC = "anotheremail@domain.com"
        .Subject = "Useful subject"
        
        Application.CutCopyMode = 0
    End With
    
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you. That is much better, but removes the signature altogether. Is there a way to get the signature to appear underneath the content?